# Hybrid CNN RNN has strong overfitting

Tags: keras, deep-learning, signal-processing, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training a neural network composed of CNN and an RNN for a multichannel signal. The problem It overfits at 50% of my simulation (multiple runs). I used adam with 0.0006 and 0.001 learning rate. Also, Batch size is about 256(for smaller same dataset ~ 2000).

I tried different size for GRU cell and I add a Batchnorm but doesn't work.

As you see when I have the obligation to use a Validation with best Val_loss but with this problem I can't get higher result than 43% with is problematic. I need just 52% for test accuracy.

What can I do to get more accuracy?

regularization?Initialisation? Relu function?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8JJQ.png

```
    x = Conv2D(F1,
               (1, 32))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x)
    x = Conv2D((C,1))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x)
    x = Activation(activation='elu')(x)
    x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1, 4))(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=r)(x)

    x = Permute((3, 1, 2))(x)
    x = Reshape((size[0], size[1]))(x)

    x = GRU(64,
            activation='tanh',
            recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
            use_bias=True,
            dropout=0.4,
            recurrent_dropout=0.4,
            implementation=1,
            input_shape=(size[0], size[1]))(x)


    x = GRU(64,
            activation='tanh',
            recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
            use_bias=True,
            dropout=0.3,
            recurrent_dropout=0.3)(x)

    x = Dense(num_classes,
              use_bias=True)(x)
    x = Activation(activation='softmax')(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

CNN have very small data-set to generalize. Also your model have many parameters to learn with small data-set, it is again a challenge.

1. Augment new examples from the training data by using some preprocessing like Rotation, Scaling, etc.
2. Dropout is a very powerful technique to control overfittting.(which you have used in cnn model, also use it in rnn model), there is spatial1D dropout for rnn, which drop one entire dim, which again helps to leverage to better generalization.